# Display the input text and the submit button on the same line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I need to put the input text field and the sumit button on the same line. I tried a lot things, but nothing worked.

The form:

```
<%= form_tag("/recherche", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= search_field_tag :recherche, params[:recherche] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Recherche", :name => nil, :id => "submit"%>
<% end %>
```

Which produces:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/recherche" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
  <input id="recherche" name="recherche" type="search" />
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Recherche" />
</form>
```

I have no idea what CSS to use... I tried with float, display, etc.

FYI, the form is wrapped in a `<li>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments, you add that you are using jQuery Mobile. This appears to be the cause of the problem, so the apparent solution would be to stop using it. But if you need it for some reason, check out how it affects your form field widths. How wide is is the `input` element? You may need to set it smaller, e.g.

```
<style>
#recherche { width: 15em; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` to your `input` tags. THe simplest way is to add this css style

```
input {
  display: inline;
}
```

This will apply the `inline` on all inputs, you may need to refine it.

Comment: I am using JQuery mobile. Your code doesn't work, I don't know why though.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are already in the same line, see:

http://jsfiddle.net/hhzFd/